# Private Key Error in AWS EC2 Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I'm getting following error when run `describe region` command. I'm in `Ubuntu 12.04`

```
$ ec2-describe-regions
Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing.
```

I have already setup following lines

```
$ export EC2_HOME=<path-to-tools>
$ export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin 
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=your-aws-access-key 
$ export AWS_SECRET_KEY=your-aws-secret-key
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The option `-K, --private-key KEY` is actually one of the *Deprecated Options*, see [Common Options for CLI Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-common-args-api.html):

> For a limited time, you can still use the private key and X.509
>   certificate instead of your access key ID and secret access key.
>   However, we recommend that you start using your access key ID (-O,
>   --aws-access-key) and secret access key (-W, --aws-secret-key) now, as the private key (-K, --private-key) and X.509 certificate (-C, --cert)
>   won't be supported after the transition period elapses. For more
>   information, see [Tell the Tools Who You Are](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/setting-up-your-tools.html#set-aws-credentials).

I highly recommend to follow the advise and only use *your access key ID (-O, --aws-access-key) and secret access key (-W, --aws-secret-key)* going forward - after all, you have them available already ;)

Accordingly, you might be able to use `-O` and `-W` explicitly, but the error actually indicates that you are simply using an outdated version of the [Amazon EC2 API tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) and might just need to update those in order to get them to automatically pick up the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` as explained and advertized in [Tell the CLI Tools Who You Are](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SettingUp_CommandLine.html#set_aws_credentials_linux).

---

### Alternative

AWS is currently establishing the [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) as *a unified tool to manage your AWS services*, which is presumably going to replace those various *Command Line Tools* per service still available on the [Tools for Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/tools/) hub. While it is still classified as a *Developer Preview*, it works quite well already and makes the entire AWS usage more streamlined and versatile, and also more discoverable, because it is supporting [Command Completion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-command-completion) for example.